# MongoDb: using string as Id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following object:

```
public class Client
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Links { get; set; }
}
```

I can create/delete it without any problems. But when I want to update the Name, it doesn't work.

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", id); //id - old name
var update = Update.Set("_id", name); //name - new name
Coll.Update(query, update);
```

ANSWER (FROM COMMENTS) the only way, as I understand, to have additional Id:

object:

```
public class Client
{
    [BsonId]
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Links { get; set; } 
}
```

Update Name:

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
var update = Update.Set("Name", name);
Coll.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: I haven't used the mongoDB c# api, but shouldn't `Update.Rename("_id", name);` be `Update.Rename("name", name);`? (_id => name)

Comment: using [BsonId], driver serializes it to _id

Comment: On the other hand, I found the answer that you can. Just you any type ( except Array ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090446/can-i-use-string-as-id-type-for-mongodb-document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `_id` is the primary key, modifying `_id` in MongoDB is not allowed.

If you need to change the unique name property, just add a unique index on it instead of using it as the primary key field.

Comment: Plz show the example. I want to set url as a primary key and then I gave this but it does not works  doc1.append("_id", url);try
               {
                coll.insert(doc1);
                
               }

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to use any other field as primary key instead of _id? Would be nice get rid of it, because i don't need it.