# Can I use String as ID type for mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, key, morphia

I am using java/morphia to deal with mongodb. The default ObjectId is not very convenient to use from Java layer. I would like to make it a String type while keep the key generation process using ObjectId, say `_id = new ObjectId.toString()`.

I want to know if there is any side effects doing it this way? For example, will it impact the database performance or causing key conflicts in any means? Will it affect the sharding environment ...

Comment: Can you explain more about why ObjectId is inconvenient? You can easily recreate one from a string like `id= new ObjectId(str)`

Comment: String is the type used in every Java program, while ObjectId is not. I don't want to introduce an new type to other components which use my library. probably it will require morphia, mongodb and bson library be imported, it's still better if people using my library is transparent to mongodb types including ObjectId

Comment: Hmm... but if your library is storing data in Mongo, won't the mongo.jar need to be in the classpath anyway? Also, there is an overhead creating and garbage collecting lots of Strings.

Comment: If you want to get a new string value for ID, use `(new ObjectId).valueOf()` instead of `(new ObjectId).toString()` (changed in MongoDB ver 2.2).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use any type of value for an `_id` field (except for Arrays). If you choose not to use ObjectId, you'll have to somehow guarantee uniqueness of values (casting ObjectId to string will do). If you try to insert duplicate key, error will occur and you'll have to deal with it.

I'm not sure what effect will it have on sharded cluster when you attempt to insert two documents with the same _id to different shards. I suspect that it will let you insert, but this will bite you later. (I'll have to test this).

That said, you should have no troubles with `_id = (new ObjectId).toString()`.

Comment: Your second and third sentence are against each other. The third is correct. Do not suspect in answers. Also, `_id`s can hold value of type `array`.

Comment: How exactly are they contradicting each other?

Comment: If you want to get a new string value for ID, use `(new ObjectId).valueOf()` instead of `(new ObjectId).toString()` (changed in MongoDB ver 2.2).

Answer (score 7):

I actually did the same thing because I was having some problem converting the ObjectId to JSON.

I then did something like

```
@Id
private String id;
public String getId() {
    return id();
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

And everything worked fine untill I decided to update a previously inserted document, when i got the object by Id sent it to the page via JSON and receive the same updated object also by  JSON post and then used the save function from the Datastore, instead of updating the previous data it inserted a new document instead of updating the one that was already.

Even worst the new document had the same ID than the previously inserted one, something i thought was impossible.

Anyway i setted the private object as an ObjectID and just left the get set as string and then it worked as expected, not sure that helps in your case thought.

```
@Id
private ObjectId id;
public String getId() {
    return id.toString();
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = new ObjectId(id);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use a string as your _id.

I'd recommend it only if you have some value (in the document) that naturally is a good unique key.  I used this design in one collection where there was a string geo-tag, of the form "xxxxyyyy"; this unique-per-document field was going to HAVE to be in the document *and* I had to build an index on it... so why not use it as a key?  (This avoided one extra key-value pair, AND avoided a second index on the collection since MongoDB naturally builds an index on "_id".  Given the size of the collection, both of these added up to some serious space savings.)

However, from the tone of your question ("ObjectIDs are not very convenient"), if the only reason you want to use a string is you don't want to be bothered with figuring out how to neatly manage ObjectIDs... I'd suggest it is worth your time to get your head around them.  I'm sure they are no trouble... once you've figured out your trouble with them.

Otherwise: what are your options?  Will you concoct string IDs EVERY TIME you use MongoDB in the future?

Comment: Hey thanks for coming back to my question asked nearly four years ago. I think I have got more understanding on MongoDB since then. And now I consider storing ObjectId as a string is really a bad idea, because ObjectId is literally three integers while the String representation of it is 24 characters, which is not efficient in terms of both space and time.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that it is not always a good idea to use the automatically generated BSON ObjectID as a unique identifier, if it gets passed to the application: it can potentially be manipulated by the user.

ObjectIDs appear to be generated sequentially, so if you fail to implement the necessary authorization mechanisms, malicious user could simply increment the value he has, to access resources he should not have access to.

**UPDATE:** Since version 3.4+ the ObjectIDs are no longer generated incrementally. Please see [3.2 docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/ObjectId/) vs [the latest docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Therefore using UUID type identifiers will provide a layer of security-through-obscurity. Of course, Authorization (is this user allowed to access requested resource) is a must, but you should be aware of the aforementioned ObjectID feature.

To get the best of both worlds, generate UUID which matches your ObjectID length (12 or 24 characters) and use it to create your own _id of ObjectID type.

Comment: "if you fail to implement the necessary authorization" you're doomed anyway. Obscurity is not security. It's only fooling yourself "we're safe".

Comment: Therefore using UUID type identifiers will provide a layer of security-through-obscurity. This is effectively a password for each document.

Comment: -1 because ObjectID are NOT generated sequentially, even though they might appear at first glance. They include timestamp, random value and then a counter https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: @DushyantBangal this is a bit rude, as the answer has been given when version 3.4 was not yet released. The answer has been correct for that version. A kinder thing to do would be to highlight the change and promote the answer to be updated (especially as this minor detail does not change the essence of the answer).

Comment: @TonySepia it still had "a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch", so that still was not sequential in the sense where you said "user could simply increment the value he has". I am sorry if think that was rude, but usually people dont even justify the -1 and give someone a chance to correct the answer.

Comment: Also, this completely changes the essence of the answer. It is completely fine to use ObjectId as a unique identifier, whereas you say its not. The answer doesn't even address the OP's question - can they use string, and will it have any performance side effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string as an ID from Java too. Here is an example method and corresponding Unit test inserting one object with a string ID in a MongoDB collection:

```
public Document insert(String json, String collectionName) {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
    BasicDBObject document = BasicDBObject.parse(json);
    Document doc = new Document(document);
    collection.insertOne(doc);
    return doc;
}

@Test
void whenInsert_ShouldInsertOne() {
    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    final String collection = "test_collection";
    final Document doc = app.insert(String.format("{\"_id\":\"%s\", \"name\": \"test\"}", 
        uuid), collection);
    assertThat(doc).isNotNull();
    final String json = app.getById(uuid, collection);
    assertThat(json).contains(String.format("\"_id\": \"%s\"", uuid));
}
```